# how to access list of Array?

Tags: arrays, jstl

```
class Obj{
            String name="Banana";
        }
        class Obj1{
            String name="Banana1";
        }
        List<Object []> arrayObjectList = [{obj,obj1},{obj,obj1}];

        <c:forEach var="list" items="${ arrayObjectList}">
            <td>
                <c:out value="${list[0].name}" />
                <c:out value="${list[1].name}" />
            </td>
        </c:forEach>
```

i am sending obj and obj1 as List list from java context.
 I want to access name property of obj and obj1. but 
        jstl output:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "list"

Comment: Post **real** code. Post the exact and complete error stack trace you get.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "list" 
this is output of exception... this is taking "list" as string but it should be "list []" . as you can see in code , i m trying to access list[0] and list[1].

sorry sir , i can't paste my code here... above code is exact code copy except all properties in both class.